# How to create show the content above the button using toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here i created toggle the content with slow motion ...but it displaying text like spreading effect 
how can remove this spreading effect

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 extra-p">
          <div class="pannel" style="display: none;">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
         </div>
        </div><!--md-12-->

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 anc-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-orange tip-btn">read more</button>
        </div><!--md-2-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tip-btn").click(function(){
        $(".pannel").toggle("slow");
        });
     });
        </script>


</body>
</html>
```

?
bootstrap jquery javascropt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `toggle` you need to use `slideToggle` which will help you to display without spreading effect

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 extra-p">
      <div class="pannel" style="display: none;">
      <p>1 . Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 anc-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-orange tip-btn">read more 1</button>
        </div><!--md-2-->
    </div><!--md-12-->
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 extra-p">
        <div class="pannel" style="display: none;">
        <p>2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 anc-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-orange tip-btn">read more 2</button>
          </div><!--md-2-->
      </div><!--md-12-->
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 extra-p">
        <div class="pannel" style="display: none;">
        <p>3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 anc-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-orange tip-btn">read more 3</button>
          </div><!--md-2-->
      </div><!--md-12-->
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 extra-p">
        <div class="pannel" style="display: none;">
        <p>4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 anc-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-orange tip-btn">read more 4</button>
          </div><!--md-2-->
      </div><!--md-12-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tip-btn").click(function(){
         $(this).closest('.extra-p').find('.pannel').slideToggle("slow");
        });
     });
        </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome @Rajashekar -:)

Comment: but how can i use this script for multiple buttons

Comment: Add `overflow:hidden` to the `pannel` class to remove the jarring opening and closing jump.

Comment: @Rajashekar code updated above you need to add  $(this).closest('.extra-p').find('.pannel').slideToggle("slow");

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use two methods to toggle content slowly :

1  `$(".pannel").slideToggle("slow")`        as mentioned in above answer

2. `$(".pannel").fadeToggle("slow);`           to display and hide content

For multiple buttons

```
<button class="tip-btn" check="div1"></button>
<button class="tip-btn" check="div2"></button>
<button class="tip-btn" check="div3"></button>
```

let div1 , div2 and div3 be the id of three divs you want to toggle

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.tip-btn).click(function(){
     var divId = $(this).attr("check");
      $('#'+divId).fadeToggle("slow");
 });
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have three more buttons like this ..but how can i add this script to them with one class name...?

Comment: You can use attributes in button for further comparison if you like where you can put information related to div which you can use for toggle purpose , let me give example above.